# Background needed for a simple RF transmitter/receiver pair

Tags: rf, radio, books

*Current background*: I'm familiar with the very basics of linear circuits, and I've played around with microcontrollers a bit.

I'd like to make a simple radio transmitter and receiver for digital data. What books or other resources might guide me along the way? I realize it may take a couple years to learn enough to actually make something.

Comment: Is this simply for the fun and learning experience, performance and legality being no issue, or do you want something that works properly and is legal? In both cases, what range and speed are you aiming at?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: It's for the learning experience. A couple meters is far enough and anything over about 10 bits/second is fast enough.

Comment: Some more detail, if you're interested: I spent a bunch of time learning about forward error correction over the past year (from a mathematical perspective), and now I want to try it out in real life. That was my original motivation for wanting to learn about this. I don't want to just buy a RF module, though: I want to learn about the electronics as well.

Comment: To address your last point, you can buy radio modules that just provide "raw" binary data transmission, to which you could add your own packetizing and error-correction algorithms.

Comment: You could research [some existing radio mudules](http://www.hoperf.com/) and then construct similar from scratch - the IC in the hearth is half of the work, I guess. Ready modules provide several kBps at several tens of meters with a half wavelength whip antenna. Also, getting something to work quickly, and then improving it, would be far better than waiting for two years to "make something from scratch".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you find an audio AM or FM transmitter receiver combo, and test it with audio. AM is probably easiest. Plenty of circuits available on the web.

Next the transmitting processor must supply the audio, using for instance FSK. At the receiving side you can use a PLL to decode the signal, google XR2211 or NE567.

Once you have an audio radio link, the problem is much like the good old telephone modem, so you can google for keywords like "FSK modem" or "300 baud modem". Or, google for casette tape storage - that too is almost the same problem as yours.